# activity is working in emulator but not in my phone

Tags: android, android-studio

When i try to run this activity in `Emulator` it runs pretty well.But when i try to run this in my phone the whole application crashes.
Any suggestion?
Actually i am trying to add a `scrollview` with both relative and linear layout.
i have also included `cardview` widget.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.rishav.carsearch.maruti01"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_maruti01"
    android:background="#E0E0E0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/card1">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@drawable/marutilogoentry"
                    android:onClick="Onignis"
                    android:clickable="true" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>




        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/swifts"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"

            android:id="@+id/card222">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@drawable/swifts"
                    android:onClick="Onignis"
                    android:clickable="true" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/swift"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/fuel"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Mileage - 25.2 Kmpl"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="4.81 - 7.44 lakhs"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1248cc"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/swifts"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"

            android:id="@+id/cardbaleno">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@drawable/baleno"
                    android:onClick="Onignis"
                    android:clickable="true" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Baleno"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/fuel"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Mileage - 27.2 Kmpl"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="5.25 - 7.58 lakhs"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1248cc"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/swifts"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"

            android:id="@+id/dzire">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@drawable/dzire"
                    android:onClick="Onignis"
                    android:clickable="true" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Swift Dzire"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/fuel"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Mileage - 26.2 Kmpl"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="5.27 - 8.58 lakhs"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1248cc"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/swifts"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"

            android:id="@+id/wagnr">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@drawable/wagonr"
                    android:onClick="Onignis"
                    android:clickable="true" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/wagonr"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/fuel"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Mileage - 27.2 Kmpl"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="4.13 - 5.18 lakhs"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="998cc"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/swifts"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"

            android:id="@+id/cardbasleno">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@drawable/ciaz"
                    android:onClick="Onignis"
                    android:clickable="true" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Maruti Suzuki Ciaz"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/fuel"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Mileage - 28.2 Kmpl"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="7.53 - 9.64 lakhs"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1248cc"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>





    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you show the error trace you get?

Comment: its says app stopped responding....but i works in emulator..

Comment: Try debugging your application on Android Studio with you mobile plugged to your computer and see what you get on the console when it crashes.